# Hypothesis formulation

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have a few questions regarding the formulation of hypotheses.

For example, here are 2 hypotheses:

1. Age will influence the choice of food individuals order at the restaurant.
2. Younger individuals are more likely to order fried food at the restaurant.

These 2 are almost the same, yet different. Does one have an advantage over the other? How does the stats analysis change, if at all? Which one would I be better off choosing?

Another example could be a hypothesis on gender and safety.

1. Gender impacts the individuals' feeling of safety when walking home at night.
2. Women are more likely to feel unsafe when walking home at night.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example:

> 1. Age will influence the choice of food individuals order at the restaurant.
> 2. Younger individuals are more likely to order fried food at the restaurant.

These could both be tested by regression models. For 1, the outcome might be multinomial, measuring whether age is associated with a change in which of the $n$ possible food choices people make. For 2, the outcome would be binary (fried food or not), so logistic regression would be more suitable. The hypothesis test on the model coefficients would be two-tailed in the first place, because you are not assuming any directionality of effect, and one-tailed in the second example, because you are specifically asking whether young people order more fried food. This assumes that young people will not order *less* fried food.

For your second example:

> 1. Gender impacts the individuals' feeling of safety when walking home at night.
> 2. Women are more likely to feel unsafe when walking home at night.

The outcome would most likely be continuous (how safe do people feel?), and the predictor in both cases would be categorical (ie, what gender are the study participants). In this case, you could test both hypotheses with the same model, something like

$$ \text{Safety}_i = \text{Sex}_i\beta + \epsilon_i$$

which could be a simple linear model. The difference would come in how you test the hypothesis. For 1, the hypothesis test would be a two-tailed test, because you are not assuming which direction the effect would be --- perhaps men are more afraid of assault than women in the areas you are examining, due to a lot of muggings, for example. For 2, the hypothesis test would be one-tailed, because you are only interested in whether being a woman is associated with a decreased feeling of safety.

It is hard to say which of these is "better", because it depends on what questions you want to answer. However, I think it is often better to ask narrow questions, because finding out that age influences food choice will just lead you to ask how, in what direction, etc. Having said that, using one-tailed tests often doesn't have huge statistical advantages, and can lead you to miss interesting effects because the direction of effect was not anticipated.

Comment: @csira_allapot_5876 I don't think the choice between the one-sided and two-sided test should be made on "statistical advantages". The important question really is whether you aim, for reasons available pre-data, at showing a particular direction of influence or not. What would not be correct is to set up the hypotheses no. 2 *after* you have seen that this is how it seems to play out in the data.